# In Lisp/Racket/Scheme how is it possible to have an argument named `list`?

Tags: arguments, scheme, lisp, racket, function-call

Isn’t `list` a *keyword* to create a new list in Lisp, but yet it is possible to have an argument called `list` in Lisp. I thought keywords in most programming languages such as Java or C++ cannot be used for *argument* *names*, is there a special reason in Lisp that they can?

Answer (score 5):

The name `list` isn't a reserved keyword, it's an ordinary function. Reusing the name for another purpose can be confusing for the reader but doesn't present any problems for the language itself; it's the same as having two variables called `x` in different parts of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Mainstream Lisp descendants and derivatives like Commmon Lisp and Scheme do not incorporate the concept of reserved keywords. It is alien to the way Lisp works.

When Lisp read syntax is scanned, identifier tokens which appear in it are converted into corresponding symbol objects. These tokens are all in the same lexical category: symbol.

When Lisp read syntax is scanned and turned into an object, such as a nested list representing program code, this is done without regard for the semantics (what the symbols mean).

This is different from the parsing of languages (such as some of those in the broad Fortran/Algol family) which have reserved keywords.

Roughly speaking, reserved keywords are tokens which look like symbols but are actually just punctuation. Lisp has punctuation also, like parentheses, sharpsign prefixes, various quotes and such.

These punctuation words have a fixed role in the phrase structure grammar, and the phrase structure grammar must be processed before the semantics of the program can be considered.

So for instance, the reserved `BEGIN` and `END` keywords in Pascal are essentially nothing more than verbose parentheses. The '`(`' and '`)`' tokens are similarly reserved in Lisp-like languages. Trying to use `BEGIN` as the name of a function or variable in Pascal is similar to trying to use `(` as the name of a function or variable in Lisp.

Some languages have keywords which determine phrase structure, yet allow identifiers which look exactly like reserved keywords to be used anyway. For instance, PL/I was famous for this:

```
IF IF=THEN THEN THEN=ELSE; ELSE ELSE=IF
```

Lisp dialects may assign special semantic treatment to certain symbols or certain categories of symbols. This is a sort of reservation, but not exactly the same as reserved keywords, because it is at the semantic level. For instance, in Common Lisp, the symbols `nil` and `t` (more specifically the `nil` and `t` in the `common-lisp` package, `common-lisp:nil` and `common-lisp:t`) may not be used as function or variable names. When either one appears as an expression, it evaluates to itself: the value of `t` is `t` and that of `nil` is `nil`. Moreover, `nil` is also the Boolean false value and the empty list. So, effectively, these symbols are reserved in some regards. Common Lisp also has a `keyword` package. All symbols in that package evaluate to themselves and may not be used as variables. They may be used as function names, and for any other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You say Lisp, but the answer changes depending on which Lisp you're talking about.

In Common Lisp, you can use `list` as a variable because Common Lisp is a Lisp-2, meaning that each symbol has a separate slot for a function binding and a variable binding.  Common Lisp sets the function binding for the symbol `list` in the CL package, but doesn't set the variable binding.  You can't change the function binding because Common Lisp doesn't allow you to redefine bindings for symbols that are set in the CL package (you can, of course, use whatever symbols you like in your own packages), but since the variable binding is free you're allowed to use it.

Scheme is a Lisp-1, which means that it only has one binding per symbol.  There's no separation of function bindings and variable bindings (hence why you use `define` in Scheme, but `defun` and `defvar` in CL).  The reason you can use "list" as a variable is because Scheme doesn't prevent you from rebinding its built-in symbols.  It's just generally a bad idea, since by redefining `list` you can no longer call the `list` function.

Emacs Lisp is a Lisp-2 but doesn't prevent you from rebinding symbols, which means you can do things like `(defun + (- a b))` and totally screw up your editing session.  So...  don't do that, unless you really know what you're doing.

Clojure is a Lisp-1.  I don't have a working Clojure install at the moment so I can't comment on what it lets you do.  I would suspect it's more strict than Scheme.

Comment: To write this answer, I opened Emacs and redefined `+` as I stated in my comment.  Emacs refuses to shut down now.  So yeah, really don't do that.